# Two way binding Android

Tags: java, android

Maybe I am missing something small here, but I cannot get my binding to work. I set it up as follow:

```
public class Toolbar extends Fragment {

//Interaction handlers
//interface for interaction with Activity
public interface ToolBarInteraction{
    public void Search(String screenName);
}

private ToolbarBind modelData;
private ToolBarInteraction mListener;

public static Toolbar newInstance() {
    return new Toolbar();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentToolbarBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_toolbar);
    modelData = ToolbarBind.newInstance();
    modelData.searchedText.set("Hello");
    binding.setModelData(modelData);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    checkMListener();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_toolbar, container, false);

    //get button to set onClick event
    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String hello = modelData.searchedText.get();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void OnSearchClicked(View view){
    mListener.Search(modelData.searchedText.get());
}

private void checkMListener(){
    try{
        mListener = (ToolBarInteraction) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement the ToolBarInteraction Interface");
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for ToolbarBind:

```
public class ToolbarBind extends BaseObservable {
private String _searchText;

public final ObservableField<String> searchedText = new ObservableField<String>();

//factory method
public static ToolbarBind newInstance(){ return new ToolbarBind(); }
}
```

And in my fragment, I set the binding up as follow, all within the `layout` tag:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="modelData"
        type="Common.CommonObjects.ToolbarBind"/>
</data>
```

And for binding to property:

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:hint="Search"
     android:text="@={modelData.searchedText}"/>
```

As can be seen, in the `onCreate` I set the text to "Hello", but even when the view displays on the phone, the EditText is not populated with this text.  When I change the value, and click my button, the value I get back in the event is "Hello", not my new text entered while the app is running.

What am I missing?

Comment: Post the code of `ToolbarBind`.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy Added the code.

Comment: @Wizard I read for two way binding, you need to have '@={}'

Comment: @monstertjie_za The `ToolbarBind` looks fine (though you don't need to extend `BaseObservable` if you use `ObservableField`). Do what @Wizard said and remove the `=`, it's not needed. There's no such thing in [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy Why would you say there is no such thing, unless I am misunderstanding something ??  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582267/how-to-perform-two-way-data-binding-with-a-togglebutton

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I misunderstood something. But I found your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you set the `Activity`'s content view to something in `onCreate(...)` but you inflate and use something different in `onCreateView(...)` as your fragment's view, which gets the model data (not the other one you created in `onCreate(...)`). I don't know exactly what you try to achieve, but I'm gonna guess that you don't want to change the `Activity`'s content view to something from the fragment, so I'm just gonna show you *a variation* of what could you use, however, you should change it to whatever pleases you.

Remove `onCreate(...)` completely then use only `onCreateView(...)` to inflate the `fragment_toolbar` layout using data binding:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    checkMListener();

    FragmentToolbarBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_toolbar, container, false);

    // FIXME you're losing data here; watch out: checking whether savedInstanceState == null is not enough because returning from backstack it will be null
    modelData = ToolbarBind.newInstance();

    // FIXME modify this so it sets the data from savedInstanceState when configuration changes
    modelData.searchedText.set("Hello");


    binding.setModelData(modelData);

    //get button to set onClick event
    binding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String hello = modelData.searchedText.get();
        }
    });

    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Watch out for the `FIXME` parts. You *could* move the `modelData` init to `onCreate(...)` which would save it from the backstack-return thing, however, configuration change will still call `onCreate(...)` unless you call `setRetainInstance(true)` on the fragment (**do not**).

Comment: Your solution provides the following: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.  
The purpose of this exercise is to learn Android development, but so far the process has been painful and slow

Comment: Are you sure you are using `DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_toolbar, container, false);`? Pay attention to the last `false` attribute as it tells the inflater not to attach the inflated view to the container.

Comment: I seem to have missed that. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it...