# How can I pass onClickListener to <include> tag?

Tags: android, android-databinding

A layout to be include is like this, **child.xml**:

```
 <layout>
       <data>
          <variable
              name="click"
              type="">   <!-- What type should be here? -->
       </data>    

       <LinearLayout>
           <View onClick="@{click}"/>
       </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

To include this, parent.xml:

```
<layout>
    <data>
       <variable
           name="viewModel"
           type="ViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout>
         <View onClick="()->viewModel.click1()"/>
         <include 
             bind:click="()->viewModel.click2()"/>
             layout="@layout/child"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

So how can I pass the clickEvent to the child.xml only. Since different parent.xml has different ViewModel, I think I shouldn't pass the viewModel to the child.xml. But I don't know how to pass method to child.xml.

The solution now I'm doing is setOnClickListener in Java File.I doubt if 
dataBinding can make it easier.

Answer (score 7):

in `child.xml`

```
<variable
    name="click"
    type="android.view.View.OnClickListener"/>


<View onClick="@{click}"/>
```

in `parent.xml`

```
<include
    layout="@layout/row"
    app:click="@{()-> viewModel.click2()}"
    />
```

There can be many ways to pass variables in `include` tag, read @[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762641/6891563).

Comment: It can not work.Since lambda and OnClickListener is different.

Comment: Did you try this? I tried my self then posted answer.

Comment: Emmm, I tried this.But some error I wrote. Sorry.T T

Comment: Let me try some more before post error.But the error I just said is resolved.

Comment: Read my answer, not for click, but you will get knowledge. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762641/6891563

Comment: Emmm, some simple mistake.First I wrote bind:onClick in parent, but click in child, So I get the compile error about lambda(That's why I said lambda and lisener are diffenet). Then some other xml error didn't resolved so I tried more time.

Comment: At last, for me the point is. I didn't know lambda will convert to OnClickListener before. I'm not sure it's convert to the DeclaredListener in View or not. That need more study.Anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: This should be accepted answer.